# await client.GetStringAsync(url) ERREUR

Tags: c#, httpclient, httpclienthandler

```
 async void GetLieu(string place)
           {

            ShowProgressDialogue("Récupération des données...");

            string MonURL = "https://hubeau.eaufrance.fr/api/v1/hydrometrie/referentiel/stations";
            string url = MonURL + "?code_departement=" + place;
           
            var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
            string result = await client.GetStringAsync(url);

            Console.WriteLine(result);
            var resultObjet = JObject.Parse(result);
```

hello,
I have a problem that I can't solve.
I can't adapt my code to prevent it crashing at the level of :

await client.GetStringAsync (url);

which would have a solution without modifying : async void GetLieu (string place)) ?

I am taker of any information.
thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others. Include the error/exception message you get and/or the problem you are getting to your question.

Comment: Is the problem solved?

Comment: my problem change "void 'to' Task 'I have a problem with my" GetLieu (place) "which no longer works. I am new to this language but I perceive ...

Comment: @michael , my answer has been updated according to your last comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Reference your last comment:***

Try this code:

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace StackOverflowWebClientQuestionAnswer
{
    public class ExternalService
    {
        public async Task<string> DownloadHomepage(string place)
        {
            string MonURL = "https://hubeau.eaufrance.fr/api/v1/hydrometrie/referentiel/stations";
            string url = MonURL + "?code_departement=" + place;

            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) " +
                                                    "AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) " +
                                                    "Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36");

                var resultat = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(new Uri(url));

                return resultat;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

***how to call it (example)?!***

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace StackOverflowWebClientQuestionAnswer.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class Resultat : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetResultat()
        {
            ExternalService external = new ExternalService();

            string resultat = await external.DownloadHomepage("971");

            return Ok(resultat);
        }
    }
}
```

***Results:***

[image: Result]

Comment: the principle is good but does not work, do you have a little alternative?

Comment: @michael how it did not work, explain please and if there is an error message provided, mention it please.

Comment: hi i have changed my code it still not working. can you tell me if you see a problem? as soon as I click to activate, the app closes.

Comment: Hi @michael , my answer has been updated according to your last comment

Comment: @michael , let me know if it worked with you, if needed I can upload a full-fledged Api example for you.

Comment: now its working i also removed in the configuration of "code compression" and how it works. A BIG THANK YOU for your help and the time you spent helping me !!! I must admit that you are very strong in the field ... thank you

Comment: @michael No worries, happy to help you, you may like to mark the answer as accepted?